# What is the JavaScript trick behind Google Chrome's automatic installation?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

If you visit https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/ and click Download Chrome, it will take you to a page where it installs chrome directly (inline) without downloading the exe and then needing you to click on it. I find this amazingly user-friendly for Windows users and I would like to emulate it, however I am completely puzzled at how they are doing it.

Any explanation or documentation about this js thingamagicks?

Comment: So, this only happens on Windows?

Comment: @FelixKling I honestly don't know, I only tried it on Windows so far

Comment: I was just asking because it downloads the disk image on Mac, so no automatic installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows it appears to be using Microsoft [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) deployment, as demonstrated in the screenshot below. It's nothing to do with JavaScript, but is something you should be able to replicate fairly easily (even for [non-.NET applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235287.aspx));

[image]

Comment: There's an "installer.min.js" in that landing page. I've prepared an unminified version of it to be observed:

https://gist.github.com/cengizc/6209385